# Separate tables for online and in-store purchases?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm developing a system for a retailer and I've hit a bit of a conundrum when it comes to deciding how to represent the orders in the database. The schema for my Order table so far is as follows:

```
Id                - PK
AccountId         - FK (Nullable)
ShippingAddressId - FK (Nullable)
BillingAddressId  - FK (Nullable)
ShippingMethod    - (Nullable)
Type              - (Nullable)
Status
Date
SubTotal
Tax
Total
```

My problem is I'm not sure whether I should represent online purchases and in-store purcahses in separate tables or not. If I were to store them in the same table, all non-nullable fields would be the only ones applicable for in-store purchases.

Another design pattern that crossed my mind is something like this:

Online order table:

```
PurchaseId        - PK, FK
AccountId         - FK
ShippingAddressId - FK
BillingAddressId  - FK
ShippingMethod
Type
```

Purchase table:

```
Id       - PK
Status
Date
SubTotal
Tax
Total
```

And for in-store purchases, there would simply be no reference from the online orders table.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a second table for location, with a primary key and location information. That could be online as well. Then use a foriegn key in your main table. You would then just fill the fields require for the application you are doing(in store, or online). This would also allow For the business to grow to more locations just by simply adding it into the location table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with the original design. Likely more maintainable and efficient as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your second design is very close to an **Entity Sub-typing** pattern.  If the primary key of your online order table was the foreign key to your purchase table then you would have entity sub-typing.

Your original design is a practical design for the physical implementation of your database because it is simple to use.  Entity sub-typing would be the preferred design at the logical level because it clearly represents your rules about which predicates (columns) belong to which logical tables.

Some people would also use the entity sub-typing pattern for their physical model too because they have an aversion to nulls.

Comment: Right, it'd definitely make more sense to just use the PurchaseId as the PK for both tables going that route. I'm just not really sure what you mean by logical/physical models. Can you elaborate on that a bit? What's the distinction?